# simplified: mysqli num_rows not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I output the number of returned rows using mysqli? My code below shows 0 though a while loop (while $s->fetch() echo $uid;) shows 2 results;

```
$m = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
$s=$m->prepare("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE token=? AND secret=?");
$s->bind_param('ss',$rt, $rs);
$rt='c';
$rs='d';
$s->execute();
$s->bind_result($uid);
$s->fetch();
print_r($s->num_rows); // RESULTS IN 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to call `mysqli_stmt::store_result()` after `mysqli_stmt::execute()` and before fetch in order to know `mysqli_stmt::num_rows`:

```php
$s->execute();
$s->store_result();
print_r($s->num_rows);
```

[PHP Document on `num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

[PHP Document on `store_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)