# Why don't i have any row results for this SQL query with MySQLI & PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code, however it always shows up as `No rows`

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT name FROM licenses WHERE `key` = ?');
if(!$stmt)
{
   $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
   echo $error;
   die();
}

$stmt->bind_param("s", $key);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->num_rows === 0)
{
   die('No rows');
}

$stmt->bind_result($name);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

Why don't I have any results? I have rows in my table.

I also tried removing the `WHERE ...` clause, but it still shows up as `No rows`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `$key`? Have you tested it?

Comment: you're just assuming the `exec()` and bind calls succeeded. try `if (!$stmt->execute()) { die($stmt->error()); }`

Comment: I have removed the where clause, causing the same results, so the `$key` is not a problem.
@MarcB I just did that, however it doesn't show any errors on the screen.. I'm clueless about what could be wrong.

Comment: This might be a duplicate: [simplified: mysqli num_rows not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13188645/4577762)

Comment: can you remove complete if block and just echo `$name` after fetching?

Comment: @Milan I tried that before too, but I get: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in`

Comment: so you first do `$stmt->fetch();` and then `echo $name;`?

Comment: @Milan yeah, but I get the error on the line before `fetch`, the line with `bind_param()`.

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem your Fatal error is not compatible with code above: `$stmt` — if boolean — can be only `False`, so your code break before `->bind_param()`. **We can't help you if you provide not coherent code**

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem can you remove `WHERE` and `$stmt->bind_param("s", $key);` and then `echo $name`?

Comment: I found the error.. It's my mistake! It's actually the next query which is failing, not this one.. But the num_rows doesn't count well in any case.