# num_rows issue with functionallity

Tags: php, mysql

Doing a project with Login, Register Options but came upon an issue with logging in to the profile.

After Inputting correct data in email, password field it doesn't echo the Success text but echoes the Incorrect Username or Password.

From what I'm seeing  `if($st->num_rows() == 1){` migt be the issue but cant seem to find how to fix it.

```
public function Login($Email, $Password){
        if(!empty($Email) && !empty($Password)){

            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE Email=? and Password=?");
            $st->bind_Param("ss", $Email,$Password);
            //$st->bindParam(2, $Password);

            $st->execute();



            if($st->num_rows() == 1){
                    echo 'Login Was Sucessfull';
                        header('Location: Success.php');
            }else {

                 echo 'Incorrect Username Or Password';
            }
        }else {
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter Username or Password");</script>';
        }


}
```

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Because `header()` redirects you to other url. You know what `header()` does, don't you?

Comment: Of you think `$st->num_rows()` is the problem have you checked what its value is?

Comment: The header isn't the issue since it doesn't get to the part when inputting correct values.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289

Comment: By Adding $st->store_result(); Problem was solved. Thanks Patrick :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simplified: mysqli num\_rows not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188645/simplified-mysqli-num-rows-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You use `$st->num_rows() == 1` to check for result, therefore your login attempt would only work if you only have **one** result, check your database if you have equal username/password combinations, or you could use `$st->num_rows() > 0` instead.

A side note also, the php header does not work if anything has already been output such as `echo 'Login Was Sucessfull';`